# why TextView can't show any data from the serial bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, textview, terminal-emulator

I need to show data to a `TextView` from a serial <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd>.
But when i connect my application with the serial device, it did connected but suddenly went forced closed. The logcat shows nothing so I don't know what's wrong.

This is the code when application listens the `inputstream` while connected:

```
public void run() {
    Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;

    while (true) {
        try {

            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            //mEmulatorView.write(buffer, bytes);

            mTextView.append(new String(buffer));
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
            //mHandler.obtainMessage(BlueTerm.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

            String a = buffer.toString();
            mTextView.setText(a);
            a = "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
            connectionLost();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and `TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataTerm);`
and on the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataTerm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

So does anyone know what went wrong?
Any answers are so helpful, thanks..

**The code that finally work**

1. On the main file, in my case named FinalSetting:
   On the Activity method, declare:

   ```
   //Layout View   
   private static TextView mTextView;
   ```

   On the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method declare the `textview`:

   ```
   mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataTerm);
   ```

   On the `Handler` method:

   ```
   case MESSAGE_READ:
       byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;              
       //mEmulatorView.write(readBuf, msg.arg1);
       // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
       String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
       //mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
       mTextView.setText(readMessage);
       break;
   ```
2. On the `BluetoothService.java` file:
   Let's just straight to the method

   ```
   //This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
   //It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.

   private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
       private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
       private final InputStream mmInStream;
       private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

       public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
           Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
           mmSocket = socket;
           InputStream tmpIn = null;
           OutputStream tmpOut = null;

           // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
           try {
               tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
               tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
           }
           mmInStream = tmpIn;
           mmOutStream = tmpOut;
       }

       public void run() {
           Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           //final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           int bytes;

           // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
           while (true) {
               try {
                   // Read from the InputStream
                   bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                   //Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                   mHandler.obtainMessage(FinalSetting.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                   connectionLost();
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       /**
       * Write to the connected OutStream.
       * @param buffer  The bytes to write
       */
       public void write(byte[] buffer) {
           try {
               mmOutStream.write(buffer);

               // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
               mHandler.obtainMessage(FinalSetting.MESSAGE_WRITE, buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
           }
       }

       public void cancel() {
           try {
               mmSocket.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
           }
       }    
   }
   ```

After you connect to the serial <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> device, the data will show up on the `TextView`.
Hope this help :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to modify **mTextView** in a non-UI thread which is illegal and might be the reason for FC (if not any other issue). However you can achieve this as below:

Change this:

```
mTextView.append(new String(buffer));
```

To this:

```
mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextView.append(new String(buffer));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks waqas, i did change it to runnable but stil FC. Then i modify it real same like the BluetoothChat example and finally work. :)